# How can I plot the animation from the csv data with date time information?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, animation

first I would like to share the data of **csv** file.

```
date, total_cases, total_deaths
12-5-2020,6,2
13-5-2020,7,3
14-5-2020,10,2
15-5-2020,18,5
```

Now I want to make an animated comparison graph where the x axis will be plotted the `dates` and y axis will be plotted the `total_cases` and `total_deaths`.

```
from matplotlib import dates as mdate
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pandas as pd


m=pd.read_csv("covid-data.csv")


m['date']=pd.to_datetime(m['date'])
m.sort_values('date',inplace=True)

cdate=m['date']
ccase=m['total_cases']
cdeath=m['total_deaths']

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

def animate(i):
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(cdate,ccase)
    ax1.plot(cdate,cdeath)
            

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000) 
plt.show()
```

Now
I can't get our desired output or animation. How can I overcome this issue and get a solution?

Sorry for my english

Comment: As the animation is running, what do you want to see changing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code:

```
from matplotlib import dates as mdate
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pandas as pd

m = pd.read_csv("covid-data.csv")

m['date'] = pd.to_datetime(m['date'], format = '%d-%m-%Y')
m.sort_values('date', inplace = True)

cdate = m['date']
ccase = m['total_cases']
cdeath = m['total_deaths']

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

def animate(i):
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(cdate[:i], ccase[:i], label = 'cases')
    ax1.plot(cdate[:i], cdeath[:i], label = 'deaths')
    ax1.legend(loc = 'upper left')
    ax1.set_xlim([cdate.iloc[0],
                  cdate.iloc[-1]])
    ax1.set_ylim([min(ccase.iloc[0], cdeath.iloc[0]),
                  max(ccase.iloc[-1], cdeath.iloc[-1])])
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdate.DayLocator(interval = 5))
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdate.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 1000)
plt.show()
```

I changed your `animate` function in order to use the `i` counter (which increases by `1` at each frame). You can control what you want to change during the animation with this counter. The I added some formatting in order to improve the visualization. The code above gives me this animation:

[image]

In order to get an appreciable animation, I added some "fake" data to the one you provided, in order to have more days over which run the animation. Replace them with your data.

---

In the case of the error

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Replace the `.iloc[0]` with `[m.index[0]]` and the same for `.iloc[-1]` with `[m.index[-1]]`. For example `ccase.iloc[0]` becomes `ccase[m.index[0]]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me very much